# No puedo terminar de instalar Delphi 10

Tags: delphi-2010

Estoy instalando `delphi 10`, me interesó que puedas desarrollar casi para cualquier plataforma sin tantas broncas (conste solo de ver, pero ya a la hora de la acción si es bastante complejo).

Pues ahora ya se ha hecho como si fuera personal, es decir lo instalo porque lo instalo, pues bien estoy atorado  con algún componente o paquete como le quieran llamar te componente es el RxLib, y realizo el siguiente procedimiento:

descomprimí el rlib en la carpeta de componentes en c:\Componentes Delphi

Incluí el directorio donde se encuentran las `unit` de 
las `Rx(...RxLib_XXX\Units)` en:

`Tools->options 
- Environment Options
- Delphi Options
- Library - Win32 | Library Path`

Abri el proyecto desde el IDE:
`File->Open: ...\RxLib_XXX\Units\RxlibXXX.bdsgroup`

intente compilar todos los paquetes:
`Project-> Build All projects.`

Aquí es donde me da un patadon, porque me manda este error, ya le di vueltas por todos lados pero nadie me dice concretamente

[dcc32 Fatal Error] RtmRxCtl230.dpk(42): E2202 Required package 'rtl' not found

donde falló? y que tengo que hacer para corregirlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no puedes instalar Delphi si el problema se presenta __al compilar un programa *dentro de Delphi*__? Puede ser que esté mal instalado, pero puede ser que estés configurando mal tu proyecto.

Comment: estoy instalando componentes, es uan lista de como 25 los que tengo que instalar, pero en este que es el 6 no pasa, me dice error 2202 falta la Liberia rtl

Comment: Agrega todos los detalles relevantes que ayuden a comprender tu problema Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para actualizarla y tendrás mas oportunidades de recibir una buena respuesta.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Delphi has instalado? y ¿Qué versión de las RxLib estás instalando?
Las RxLib tienen diferentes versiones/paquetes para cada versión de Delphi. Por el error me da que estás instalando una versión incorrecta.
Si no recuerdo mal la versión "230" que aparece en el nopmbre del package corresponde a Delphi XE2.

Comment: instale la 10.0 seatle, y descargue la Versión 2.75 de esta librería que es la que estoy poniendo